# ffmpeg capture streams in sync

Tags: ffmpeg, synchronization, video-streaming

I'd like to capture multiple real-time video streams arriving on rtp protocol, using ffmpeg. When I initiate the recording, by issuing the `ffmpeg  <command line parameters>` command, it always takes a while for the connection to built up and the actual recording to begin. This might be more than 2 seconds in certain cases, which cause a constant time difference at the replay.

How can I extract the information containing the time of the first actually recorded frame from ffmpeg? If it's not possible with ffmpeg without editing the source (which I did, and would like to avoid for other reasons), is there any similar multi-platform open-source tool which could be used?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible without effort on your side. Use something like live555 to capture your streams. All your sources must synchronize to a single clock using ntp and then rtp timestamps can be used at the receiver end to synchronize the various streams. This is not trivial and is used in video conferencing systems. I am not aware of any free implementation of the same.

If you do not have control over the sources then you are out of luck because there is no such things as a common base time across the streams. If you do, you still need to modify live555 and your player to synchronize using the timestamps on the streams and the ntp clock. Like I said, not trivial.

Perhaps gstreamer might already have plugins for it, its been a while since I used it so I am not sure. You could take a look there. (gstreamer.net).

Comment: I see, thanks! Actually the absolute time sync of the streamer servers is not so important for me: it is enough if I know when the stream recording begins, as I record them on the same PC, and the player already supports an initial delta time difference between the replayed videos.